# Error in Hibernate Tool in Eclipse Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, c3p0

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">cisadm</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:CCB240</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">cisadm</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>    
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**hibernate.properties**

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver 

hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:CCB240

hibernate.connection.username = cisadm
hibernate.connection.password = ENC(YoYU3xkTjrrX1hIbldx9DhkGadCBjvliVNh/i4CWQvg=)
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hibernate.show_sql = false
hibernate.max_fetch_depth = 2
hibernate.transaction.factory_class = org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory

hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size = 100
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 30   
hibernate.query.factory_class=org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache = false
hibernate.query.substitutions = true 'Y', false 'N'    

hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment=1
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=180
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=60
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=0
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=10
```

And my Hibernate Tool Configuration are in the link below.

[Tool Configuration](http://tinypic.com/a/2thn5/4)

But when I run the hql in HQL Editor I get the below error

```
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:193)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:139)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:208)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:85)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:165)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:139)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2259)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2255)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1724)
at org.jboss.tools.hibernate4_0.HibernateExtension4_0$3.execute(HibernateExtension4_0.java:118)
at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
at org.jboss.tools.hibernate4_0.HibernateExtension4_0.execute(HibernateExtension4_0.java:211)
at org.jboss.tools.hibernate4_0.HibernateExtension4_0.buildSessionFactory(HibernateExtension4_0.java:110)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(ConsoleConfiguration.java:283)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.execute(ExecuteQueryAction.java:82)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.run(ExecuteQueryAction.java:56)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.runWithEvent(ExecuteQueryAction.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:452)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate connection provider [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider]
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:190)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:112)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:54)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:69)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:183)
... 48 more
```

***I am adding the hibernate-c3p0-4.1.0.Final.jar and in the drop down I am selecting Hibernate version as 4. What am I doing wrong?***

I am using:

- JBoss Hibernate Tool 3.3
- Eclipse Indigo

Comment: Looking at your configuration everything looks correct. The point is that you have classnotfound for  

       org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider


Which should is in hibernate-c3p0-4.1.0.Final.jar.
Can zou check your project classpath. Eventuallz set a breakpoint in  the exception throw

Comment: Thanks for ur inputs but I already have the c3p0 in the classpath if u can see the link for [link] http://tinypic.com/a/2thn5/4 [/link] Tools Configuration above i have added it in classpath but still this error comes can u plz suggest

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same problem, could you solve it finally?

Answer (score 1):

I write here as in comments is difficult to be clear. In the class

```
  org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator
```

put a breakpoint in the method below, in the return statement.  It causes the exception thrown in your runtime. In debug mode we will understand what is happening and ,hopefully, complete this reply:

```
private ConnectionProvider More ...instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(
        String providerClassName,
        ClassLoaderService classLoaderService) {
    try {
        LOG.instantiatingExplicitConnectionProvider( providerClassName );
        return (ConnectionProvider) classLoaderService.classForName( providerClassName ).newInstance();
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        throw new HibernateException( "Could not instantiate connection provider [" + providerClassName + "]", e );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your inputs.
Actually whats happening is my java project has hibernate version 4.1 and my hibernate tools plugin is using hibernate 3.5.1 when I use c3p0 hibernate-c3p0-3.5.1-Final.jar as its for hibernate 3.5 and changed the hibernate tools configuration Main tab to hibernate version to 3.5 its working fine. But I want to use hibernate version 4.1.0 and c3p0 hibernate-c3p0-4.1.0.Final.jar. Plz suggest me what configuration should I doi to use Hibernate 4.1 in eclipse Indigo

Comment: You configure the tools to use hibernate 4.1, you use c3p0 4.1 and should work. If not it means that your application server is loading still hibernate 3.5.1. Therefore zou will need to change the application server classpath.

Comment: My application server and web dynamic project in eclipse project already has 4.1 in class path but the prob arises in my hibernate tools i.e jboss tools(hibernate console) in this i am getting this error

Comment: let me understand.1) project hib 3.5.1, tools plugin hib 3.5.1, c3p0-3.5.1 => OK.  2) project hib 4.1, tools plugin hib 4.1, c3p0-4.1 => False! If 2) is like that I am quite sure that you think to have the 2) setup but in runtime the versions are not matching. Putting the debug where I said you can verify 100% what is happening. Check this and then I have a better picture.

Comment: In 
1)project hib 4.1.0, jboss tools plugin hib 3.5.1, c3p0-3.5.1 =>  ok
2)project hib 4.1.0, jboss tools plugin hib 4.1.0, c3p0-4.1.0 =>  error
So in both the cases I am having proj hib set to 4.1.0. and in the proj is .jar for all pojo which I have included in the class path and I am just trying to run the HQL Editor so thts the reason I am not able to figure where to put the above logic u have provided

Comment: putting the breakpoint in the bad case what do you see? In the stack. Without that we cannot decide anything.

Comment: there is no class which is invoking the HQL editor the error is above which only coming in the case if i run a hql in hql editor in the case 2). So i m unable to put breakpoint. only error i get is above

Comment: got it. did you installed the eclipse plugin from here? http://www.jboss.org/tools/download If it is not working with your conf you have found a bug that need to be reported. but u can workaround it.... Check the link, be sure to install the last and retry your stuff. If it is not working for me it is a bug not your fault.

Comment: S I have downloaded from this site only. But the latest version of jboss tools is for eclipse Kepler but I am using eclipse Indigo and even in latest jboss tool the hibernate version is not 4.1 but jboss version is 4.1 which is mentioned in the features file.The latest jboss version 4.1 has hibernate version 3.7 but not hib 4.1. So plz let me know if any work around exists

Comment: I don't have eclipse installed here now. if you are crazy enough: start eclipse passing -cp <the jar 4.1final> and see what happens. I will check at home in case the problem is still open.

Comment: Any luck did u try that?

Comment: working till midnight, I couldn't.... try this in the meanwhile http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_a_library_to_the_classpath_of_a_plug-in%3F

Answer (score 1):

**add** mysql driver jar in classpath.

> mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar

Answer (score 0):

problem is our hibernate configuration file.change the configuration with this code.

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:<port>:<sid></property>
<property name="connection.username">username</property>
<property name="connection.password">password</property>

<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-5.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql//localhost/db_catalogue_glsid</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <mapping class="metier.entite.Produit"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: When you answer a question, you may also want to describe what changes you have done briefly.